# Xamarin.forms quickblox

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, quickblox

I am using xamarin.forms for making chat application. I am currently trying to run sample app of `quickblox` which is in xamarin.forms. In this sample app I am getting users but not able to send and receive message.

This line `PrivateChatManager.SendMessage(encodedMessage);` gives me this error message:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Not connected to XMPP server.   at
>   Xmpp.Client.XmppClient.AssertValid () [0x00021] in
>   :0    at
>   Xmpp.Client.XmppClient.SendMessage (Xmpp.Jid to, System.String
>   messageId, System.String body, System.String subject, System.String
>   thread, System.Xml.Linq.XElement extraParamets, Xmpp.Im.MessageType
>   type, System.Globalization.CultureInfo language) [0x00000] in
>   :0    at
>   Quickblox.Sdk.Modules.ChatXmppModule.ChatXmppClient.SendMessage
>   (System.String jid, System.String body, System.Xml.Linq.XElement
>   extraParams, System.String dialogId, System.String subject,
>   Xmpp.Im.MessageType messageType) [0x00012] in
>   :0    at
>   Quickblox.Sdk.Modules.ChatXmppModule.PrivateChatManager.SendMessage
>   (System.String message) [0x0002a] in
>   :0    at
>   XamarinForms.QbChat.ViewModels.PrivateChantViewModel.SendMessageCommandExecute
>   (System.Object obj) [0x0006e] in
>   D:\RND\quickblox-dotnet-sdk-master\sample-chat\XamarinForms\XamarinForms.QbChat\ViewModels\PrivateChantViewModel.cs:188

Comment: did you follow all of the instructions for creating an account and registering an API key?

Comment: are you talking about the QuickBlox account.I have created one testApp on Quickblox site.And created 3 users.Not getting what is registering API key

Comment: Please help i am new in xamarin.forms

Comment: I also found that all API of ChatXmppModule are giving me this error NotifyAboutGroupUpdate API also gives me same error....

Comment: This is more than likely not a problem in Xamarin Forms but in QuickBlox or your configuration of QuickBlox. As Jason suggets I would check if your account is set up correctly and if you're calling the APIs as you should. Also, if you're new to Xamarin Forms I would recommend trying to build a simpler sort of app first.

Comment: when you create a new QuickBoxClient() you have to pass in a key for YOUR account.

Comment: @nitu did you fix this issue? I am facing same issue in android 8.0 now